# Referencing javascript object within jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code.

```
var NotificationsBox={
    HideNotificationBox:function()
    {
          document.getElementById("NotificationBox").style.visibility="hidden"; 
    },
    toggleNotificationBox:function()
    {
        $('#NotificationBox').toggle();             
    },
    SetContainerClick_NotificationHide_Event:function()
    {
        $('#Container').click(this.HideNotificationBox);        
    },
    SetNotificationBoxClick_NotificationToggleEvent:function()
    {
        $('#ShowNotification').click(function(){
            $(this).html("0");
            $(this).css("background-color","#000");

            this.toggleNotificationBox();     ///  <-- PROBLEM
        });
    }

};

NotifyBox=Object.create(NotificationsBox);
NotifyBox.HideNotificationBox();
NotifyBox.SetContainerClick_NotificationHide_Event();
NotifyBox.SetNotificationBoxClick_NotificationToggleEvent();
```

Now you can see what the problem is. Here `this` will reference to the `#ShowNotification` and I want to reference `NotificationBox` here so that I can call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to `this` before binding `click`, and use this reference instead of `this` within the `click` event handler:

```
SetNotificationBoxClick_NotificationToggleEvent:function()
{
    var self = this;
    $('#ShowNotification').click(function(){
        $(this).html("0");
        $(this).css("background-color","#000");

        self.toggleNotificationBox(); //  <-- self will refer to NotificationsBox
    });
}
```

Or, as an alternative, use `NotificationsBox.toggleNotificationBox()`, though this will cease to work if you happen to change the name of the variable `NotificationsBox`:

```
SetNotificationBoxClick_NotificationToggleEvent:function()
{
    $('#ShowNotification').click(function(){
        $(this).html("0");
        $(this).css("background-color","#000");

        NotificationsBox.toggleNotificationBox();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think will stick with the first option Thnx alot.

Comment: @Mj1992: Yes, it's de *de facto* way of doing it in JavaScript. You're welcome!